# Serialize Base Class Implementation for all "new" Properties

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, xml-serialization

I have a bunch of classes that were auto-generated from an XSD, and provided to me in a compiled DLL for which I don't have the source code.  I have a need to add interfaces to each of the types, which resulted in code such as the following:

```
public interface IBar
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo<TBar> where TBar : IBar
{
    TBar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BarWrapper : BarFromXSD, IBar
{
}

public class FooWrapper : FooFromXSD, IFoo<BarWrapper>
{
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public new BarWrapper Bar
    {
        get { return base.Bar as BarWrapper; }
        set { base.Bar = value; }
    }
}
```

If the client gives me a DLL where any of the interfaces to the underlying types changes, I will get compile-time errors telling me such.  However, that is NOT true if the serialization attributes change in the underlying DLL.  In that case, my wrapper classes will happily serialize into objects that are incompatible with the associated XSDs.

The other issue with the above code is that it simply doesn't work.  When I try to create an `XmlSerializer` for objects of type `FooWrapper`, I get the exception chain:

> There was an error reflecting type 'MyNamespace.FooWrapper'.
>   There was an error reflecting property 'Bar'.
>   Member FooWrapper.Bar of type MyNamespace.BarWrapper hides base class member cs_Foo.Bar of type DLLNamespace.Bar. Use XmlElementAttribute or XmlAttributeAttribute to specify a new name.

To avoid this issue, I would like to do the simpler of either:

> 1) Override default serialization, in order to ignore the "new" property implementations, or
>   2) Reflectively copy all XML serialization attributes from the base class to the derived class

The issues that I am trying to address with any potential solution are:

> 1) I would like to perform reflection once, in the static constructor, to determine the serialized element/attribute names and namespaces.
>   2) I have multiple classes that follow the same pattern as `FooWrapper`, so any solution should would work for any such classes.
>   3) The classes that follow the `FooWrapper` pattern can contain other properties not defined in the base class that require serialization.
>   4) The ideal solution should gracefully handle new properties.  For example, if at a later time I add or remove a "new" property, I shouldn't have to add/remove other methods, or have to hard-code the name of the "new" property in the static constructor.

Any insight to a solution that meets these requirements is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With XML serialization an inherited class add an attribute to the xml to distinguish between child classes.  Without this attribute you won't be able to read the xml using serialization.  So it has to be added into the dll also.  You nay have to just write you own code that reads and parses the xml instead of using the standard xml serialization.

Comment: I never need to deserialize any of the `FooWrapper` pattern types.  I want them to be serialized as if I was serializing type Foo, but with potentially additional attributes (for example, ALL elements can have an xsi:type attribute).  As for writing my own code, that is fine, but it would have to work by default with `XmlSerializer`, as the DLL that I can't modify has methods that create an `XmlSerialer` based on the object that is passed to the method.  Therefore, any solution must be compatible with the `new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooWrapper))` constructor.

Comment: What methods are going to be used to De-Serializer.  If you are modifying a Serializer the real concerns are the code that will later De-Serialize the code.  There is no issues in changing the Serializer if you can also change the De-Serialization.

Comment: I am not deserializing the result at all.  I am simply generating XML from objects, then sending that XML to another server for processing.  I want to modify the classes to implement interfaces, since multiple versions of the same XSD have similar structures.  If each class implements a common interface, I can perform common logic across multiple versions.  However, I don't have access to the source code of the generated classes.  Therefore, I need some way to generate the same XML using custom classes that inherit from the classes I can't modify.  Is there some way to do that?

Comment: I don't know what the Server expects so I can't answer the question.

Comment: The server expects the objects to be serialized EXACTLY as they would be if the type being serialized is `FooFromXSD`, instead of `FooWrapper`.  To simplify, how can I inherit from a class in order to implement an interface on that class, but still have the resulting serialized XML be identical, as if the inheritance does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of xml with inheritance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root() {
                bar = new Bar1() {
                    foo = "123"
                }
            };


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root 
    {
        public Bar bar {get;set;}
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Bar1))]
    [XmlRoot("Bar")]
    public class Bar 
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot("Bar1")]
    public class Bar1 : Bar
    {
        [XmlElement("foo")]
        public string foo {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Look at the XML.  A 'type' attribute is added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <bar d2p1:type="Bar1" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <foo>123</foo>
  </bar>
</Root>
```

Comment: A couple of issues with your example. First, I don't control the serialization code. The existing code (which I am unable to modify) is `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlObj.GetType()); serializer.Serialize(xmlObj);` Given this constraint, is there a way to get rid of the d2p1:type attribute on "bar" (which wouldn't be there without the inheritance)?  Also, the property `foo` needs to be added to class `Bar`, and overwritten (using the "new" keyword) in `Bar1`.  My question is, is it possible to generate the XML you generated, minus the d2pi:type attribute, given these constraints?

Comment: You can't get rid of the type attribute using Serialization.  That is what I've been saying all along.